# Value of resistor clarification

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, resistors, resistance, pullup

I'm using this device - [USB2514B](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00001692C.pdf)

Table 3-3 says that the required resistor value is: "47 - 100 kohm". I assumed that the 47 was 47 ohms and not 47 kohms. I used 10 kohm resistors in my designs. Everything seemed to work OK. Now I have some boards that do not work consistently. I replaced the 10 kohm resistors with 100 kohm and the board works. Does the 47 really mean 47 kohm?

Comment: If the "k" doesn't apply to both numbers, then neither should the "ohm". Have you tried a resistor of 47 cm, or maybe 47 °C? Or just 47 resistors? ;)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, that's a nice way to put it

Comment: Sometimes understanding spec sheets requires decoding ambiguous language. English majors don't write this stuff.

Comment: Obviously 47-100 = -53 kohm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would read that as [47 to 100] Kohm.  Since the unit is only mentioned once, it should apply to both numbers.

Also, looking at the material after Table 3-3, resistor values are shown as "R K Ohm"

Comment: Looking at the same table, a spread of 47 Ohms to 100 kOhms strikes one as unreasonably large for an LED circuit.